# Symfony, update 3.4 => 4.4. Monolog error

Tags: symfony4

I am trying to update a simple web application from Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 4.4.

Eventually I get the following error

```
>php bin/console debug:config

In ScalarNode.php line 36:
Invalid type for path "monolog.handlers.main.channels.elements.0". Expected scalar, but got object.
```

I am not sure what that means. Is there some new way to configure Monolog?

Answer (score 5):

I had this error and I just had to make the channels parameters as a string for example:

`channels: ["!event"]` instead of `channels: [!event]`

that just solved my problem

Comment: Thanks a lot! This definitely solved the issue!